# Custom collection in Scala on Android - TraversableFactory crashes with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, scala, noclassdeffounderror, scala-collections

I'm trying to implement a custom collection, so I'm following [this post](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html).

Now, the 'bare' code that leads to a crash is this:

```
object TraversableCollection extends TraversableFactory[TraversableCollection] {
    implicit def canBuildFrom[T] : CanBuildFrom[Coll, T, TraversableCollection[T]] = new GenericCanBuildFrom[T]
    
    def newBuilder[T] = new ListBuffer[T].mapResult(x => new TraversableCollection(x:_*))
}

class TraversableCollection[T](seq : T*) extends Traversable[T]
                                         with GenericTraversableTemplate[T, TraversableCollection]
                                         with TraversableLike[T, TraversableCollection[T]] {
    override def companion = TraversableCollection  
    def foreach[U](f: T => U) = seq.foreach(f)
}
```

My whole implementation is not much more complicated, it's just a collection that wraps an immutable `Vector` that can move forward and backward over items, storing the index value internally and exposing 'current' item. So essentially - a two-way iterator.

Anyway, the whole implementation (both the skeleton above, and my full implementation) works just fine in REPL (here's a full implementation):

```
scala> val vec = Vector("Just", "testing", "it")
vec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(Just, testing, it)

scala> val t = new TraversableCollection(vec:_*)
t: TraversableCollection[String] = (Just, testing, it)

scala> t.current
res6: String = Just

scala> t.moveForward(2)

scala> t.current
res8: String = it

scala> t.moveBack(1)

scala> t.current
res10: String = testing
```

Simple and I need it. Here's the problem though: in the Android app, when I get to the point when the collection is created, `PathClassLoader` starts crashing, then gets to:

```
this: NoClassDefFoundError 
detailMessage: "scala.collection.generic.TraversableFactory"
```

and dies with this in the log:

```
05-16 12:14:35.056: E/AndroidRuntime(575): java.lang.VerifyError: my.package.data.TraversableCollection
```

Why? Is there anything I can do about it?

Now my temporary solution is to remove the `GenericTraversableTemplate` and `TraversableLike`, and leave the `Traversable` trait. Not perfect, but would kind-of work for now.

Setup:

- Eclipse from ADT, Scala IDE plugin + AndroidProguardScala plugin
- Scala 2.10.0-2012-12-05

#### [EDIT] Proguard related

From my very, very limited knowledge about Proguard, it seems it should be disabled, because the path is commented out in `project.properties`:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I tried commenting and uncommenting the line, along with adding this to proguard-project.txt:

```
-keepnames scala.collection.generic.TraversableFactory
```

I'm still having the same error no matter what.

#### [EDIT 2] Still Proguard related

Here's the default configuration that the AndroidProguardScala generates (and which is used when the app crashes):

```
-injars "F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\373\1\.cp\lib\scala-library.jar"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-injars "F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\373\1\.cp\lib\scala-actors.jar"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-injars "F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\372\1\.cp\lib\scala-reflect.jar"(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)

-outjars "F:\Projects\AndroidScalaProject\proguard_cache\jartender_cache_7212076580182750151.jar"
-injars "F:\Projects\AndroidScalaProject\bin\classes"
-libraryjars "F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar"
-libraryjars "F:\Projects\AndroidScalaProject\libs\android-support-v4.jar"

-keep public class * extends android.**
-dontwarn **$$anonfun$*
-dontwarn
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-ignorewarnings
-forceprocessing

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class scala.ScalaObject { *; }
-keep public class scala.Function0, scala.Function1

# Fix for https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5397 

-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike {
    public protected *;
}

# AndroidProguardScala version: 0.0.47.201302150529

-keep class ...
-keep class ... # and a looot of that for anon-functions and classes in the project.
# Here's one that's interesting:
-keep class my.project.data.TraversableCollection {*;}
```

Comment: maybe proguard is getting a bit too greedy and throws away `TraversableFactory`. Does the AndroidProguardScala plugin shows you the proguard warnings in the output? it should be mentioned there.

Comment: @gourlaysama Good point, I've added an edit...

Comment: What is your Proguard configuration?

Comment: @F.X. Using the default [AndroidProguardScala](https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala) settings for the debug version. I haven't even tried configuring Proguard as a standalone for release yet. I'll add the configuration that the plugin generates.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what's going wrong there... :/